How many solutions with equation n*x*y*z*w = (x + n) (y + n) (z + n) (w + n)?
How many solutions are there for equation $n*x*y*z*w = (x + n) (y + n) (z + n) (w + n)$
if {n, x, y, z, w} are all integers and $n>1$ and $ 0 < x <= y <= z <= w$?
For example,when n=31,there are 97 solutions as the following:
{{2,36,3264,75280865},{2,36,3265,9412964},{2,36,3267,3424973},{2,36,3283,565037},{2,36,3317,205623},{2,36,3410,76849},{2,36,3685,28799},{2,36,3813,22847},{2,36,4154,15345},{2,36,4433,12462},{2,36,4774,10385},{2,37,1395,533324},{2,38,897,237336},{2,38,930,23529},{2,39,665,237336},{2,39,671,58590},{2,39,682,24955},{2,39,775,4774},{2,39,930,2387},{2,42,383,5152851},{2,43,341,41292},{2,44,305,58590},{2,44,310,15345},{2,44,465,930},{2,45,279,25916},{2,55,154,147963},{2,55,155,23994},{2,57,143,237336},{2,62,123,78771},{2,62,124,15345},{2,65,114,237336},{2,72,99,207545},{2,76,93,36487},{2,77,93,6696},{2,78,90,4497449},{3,18,6456,167513801},{3,18,6458,18618383},{3,18,6460,9859829},{3,18,6461,7982996},{3,18,6468,3424973},{3,18,6479,1807610},{3,18,6494,1101275},{3,18,6503,892738},{3,18,6510,778379},{3,18,6545,475664},{3,18,6566,386291},{3,18,6664,207545},{3,18,6665,206584},{3,18,6696,180761},{3,18,6851,112406},{3,18,6944,92225},{3,18,7259,58590},{3,18,7378,51863},{3,18,7595,43214},{3,18,8330,28799},{3,18,8618,25823},{3,18,10013,18228},{3,18,10540,16709},{3,18,11501,14756},{3,19,930,5270},{3,20,434,26877},{3,28,104,1399185},{3,31,85,14384},{3,34,72,207545},{3,36,66,3424973},{4,13,665,237336},{4,13,671,58590},{4,13,682,24955},{4,13,775,4774},{4,13,930,2387},{4,14,305,58590},{4,14,310,15345},{4,14,465,930},{4,15,217,2852},{4,17,122,58590},{4,21,72,207545},{4,23,61,58590},{5,10,619,594828},{5,10,620,240219},{5,10,744,3813},{5,11,243,475664},{5,11,244,58590},{5,12,154,147963},{5,12,155,23994},{5,13,114,237336},{5,14,93,6696},{5,27,31,14384},{6,8,999,207545},{6,8,1001,147963},{6,8,1147,7657},{6,8,1209,5735},{6,9,248,5735},{6,11,98,147963},{6,12,77,147963},{6,14,55,147963},{7,8,186,7657},{8,9,72,207545}}
2 questions:
How to find the least n that the equation has no solutions?
How to find the integer n with the most solutions?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
